# Selenium 4 network interceptor not accepting 422 http status code response

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am using selenium 4 network interceptor to intercept and mock http requests. When I try to generate a response with http code **422** , interceptor is generating an error as below.

```
{"id":14,"error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Invalid http status code or phrase"},"sessionId":"40DE1DDA6AA8E5A60725650C8BE99C3C"}
```

Here is the Fetch `fulfillRequest`

```
{
"id":14,
"method":"Fetch.fulfillRequest",
"params":{
    "requestId":"interception-job-1.0",
    "responseCode":422,
    "responseHeaders":[
        {
            "name":"date",
            "value":"Wed, 26 Jul 2023 17:42:16 GMT"
        },
        {
            "name":"server",
            "value":"nginx\u002f1.18.0 (Ubuntu)"
        },
        {
            "name":"vary",
            "value":"Accept"
        },
        {
            "name":"p3p",
            "value":"CP=\"NOI ADM DEV PSAi OUR OTRo STP IND COM NAV DEM\""
        },
        {
            "name":"strict-transport-security",
            "value":"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
        },
        {
            "name":"x-powered-by",
            "value":"Express"
        },
        {
            "name":"content-type",
            "value":"text\u002fhtml; charset=utf-8"
        },
        {
            "name":"location",
            "value":"https:\u002f\u002fcareers.uchealth.org\u002fjobs\u002f12884253-pharmacy-technician-ii?_ccid=16903933360707wca2n1fd"
        },
        {
            "name":"Set-Cookie",
            "value":"source=loz;domain=.app-cast.com;path=\u002f"
        },
        {
            "name":"Set-Cookie",
            "value":"cc_ut=16903933360707wca2n1fd;domain=.app-cast.com;path=\u002f"
        },
        {
            "name":"cache-control",
            "value":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        }
    ],
    "body":""
},
"sessionId":"40DE1DDA6AA8E5A60725650C8BE99C3C"
}
```

When I try with the same request with 200 http code, it works fine.